# How can I include devise usernames on rails logs (using graylog2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, graylog2

Is there a way to include the logged in user in rails logs?  I am using devise and graylog2, the latter of which I assume is inconsequential to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Devise provides a `current_user` [helper in the controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) which can be used to access the currently signed-in user.

Assuming the user model has a `name` attribute, you can do the following:

```
::Rails.logger.info "The currently logged-in user is #{current_user.name}"
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to know.  I was hoping though to include the username in the things that are logged already.  It would be nice not to have to output a second log item for each of items in the log already.